# Auto-correlation in saga for Requst/Reply

Tags: rebus, saga

I wanted to ask, do I understand it correctly that thanks to this https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/issues/105 when I do saga for Request/Reply I can leave `ConfigureHowToFindSaga` empty?

If it's true it would be nice to mention it in Wiki page, as well as the need for registering saga in adapter :)

The code below seems to work, could you please see if it's ok?

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static IBus bus;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var adapter = new BuiltinContainerAdapter();

            adapter.Register<SampleSaga>(() => new SampleSaga(bus));

            bus = Configure.With(adapter)
                             .Logging(l => l.ColoredConsole())
                             .Transport(t => t.UseMsmq("enpoint1", "endpoint1_errors"))
                             .MessageOwnership(x => x.FromRebusConfigurationSection())
                             .Sagas(x => x.StoreInMemory())
                             .CreateBus()
                             .Start();

            bus.SendLocal(new SampleMessage() { Test = "Hi there" });
        }
    }

    class SampleSaga : Saga<MessageHolder<SampleMessage>>,
                                           IAmInitiatedBy<SampleMessage>,
                                           IHandleMessages<Response>
    {
        IBus bus;

        public SampleSaga(IBus bus)
        {
            this.bus = bus;
        }

        public override void ConfigureHowToFindSaga()
        {
        }

        public void Handle(SampleMessage message)
        {
            Data.Message = message;
            bus.Send(new Request());
        }

        public void Handle(Response message)
        {
            Console.Write(string.Format("Response arrived. Holded message: {0}", Data.Message.Test));
            MarkAsComplete();
        }
    }

    class MessageHolder<T> : ISagaData
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public int Revision { get; set; }
        public T Message { get; set; }
    }

    class SampleMessage
    {
        public string Test { get; set; }
    }
}


namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static IBus bus;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var adapter = new BuiltinContainerAdapter();

            adapter.Handle<Request>(x => bus.Reply(new Response()));

            bus = Configure.With(adapter)
                             .Logging(l => l.ColoredConsole())
                             .Transport(t => t.UseMsmq("endpoint2", "endpoint2_errors"))
                             .MessageOwnership(x => x.FromRebusConfigurationSection())
                             .CreateBus()
                             .Start();
        }
    }

    public class Request
    {

    }

    public class Response
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's true, and I agree with you that it should be documented somewhere :)

The feature has been there for quite some time now, though, and I haven't used it that much - mostly because I feel that it's a little bit *too black box* to be immediately understandable, which I think code should be most of the time.

My feelings could be caused by me having used the feature too little, though, so I might get another feeling some time in the future :)

Your code looks fine, and I think it should work perfectly. Now, I know it's just a simple POC, but please remember to "host" your container adapter somewhere for the duration of the application lifetime, and please remember to dispose it when the application shuts down.

Comment: thank you :) by adapter "hosting" do you mean e.g. having field keeping reference to adapter like I do with bus?

Comment: yes - if you're using the builtin container adapter, you don't need to keep the adapter around though - it's ok to just keep the `IBus` reference, as long as you remember to dispose it when the application shuts down

Comment: but usually, you'd be better off using a real IoC container that can inject dependencies (including `IBus`) - and when you're working with IoC containers, you'd usually treat the container as some sort of global root level object that holds the entire application, which is what you should keep doing also when you let Rebus put itself into the container :)